# Shuffling an Array in Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, shuffle

I am very new to Programming and am trying to make a program that takes a number from an EditText then generates and Array which is then shuffled and the shuffled numbers come out on toast.
This is what my code looks like.
I have tried reading through a number of other posts on shuffling arrays but I haven't been able to get this to work.

```
public class Home extends Activity  {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);


        final EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);  
        Button  goButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.goButton);
        goButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                String no = editText1.getText().toString();
                int no2 = Integer.parseInt(no);

                int[] integerArray = new int[no2];
                for (int i = 0; i < no2; i++)  
                    integerArray[i] = i;

                Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(integerArray));
                {



                    Toast msg= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  integerArray[no2], Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

                    msg.show();
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help.
Tom

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually you don't use the array that you shuffled, but the integer array that you created.
Try instead :

```
List<Integer> myArray = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(integerArray));
Collections.shuffle(myArray);
```

And then

```
Toast msg= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  myArray.get(no2-1), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
msg.show();
```

Another better approach would be to directly create the List.

```
 List<Integer> myArray = new ArrayList<Integer>(no2);
            for (int i = 0; i < no2; i++)  
                myArray.add(i);

        Collections.shuffle(myArray);
```

Comment: Thank you for posting a reply, I haver tried both meothed and it is crashing after I've input the number the error log says that it is an outofbounds exception?'  List<Integer> myArray = new ArrayList<Integer>(no2);
                  for (int i = 0; i < no2; i++)  
                      myArray.add(i);

              Collections.shuffle(myArray);
                  {
 
  Toast msg= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), myArray.get(no2), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    
    msg.show();'

Comment: Sorry my fault. Arrays are 0 based indexing. So to get the last elem of the array you should do `myArray.get(no2-1);` See my edit.